# SEO: How does Google index Angular applications 2016

Tags: angularjs, seo, google-search

What is current situation with indexing of Angular applications?
There were so many rumours that google understood Angular client side compilation. But we are still struggling with making it understand our dynamic title.

[image]

You can check it out [here](https://www.google.nl/#q=studytube).

**UPD**: Also asked on [Google Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/s597p0CtN0I;context-place=forum/webmasters).

**UPD2**: now it's not there, but only because I put default text inside and use **ng-attr-**, like so:

```
<meta name="description"
      content="Some default description not to show the variable."
      ng-attr-content="{{ metadata.description | translate }}"/>
```

Comment: probably do better asking in google support groups. They claim they [have SPA's under control](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) without prerender

Comment: @STEVER is it already solve right? Do you change something or it was just a matter of time?

Comment: I had to put "default text inside tags" and use ng-bind instead of having {{expression}}, but it does not solve outputting dynamic content issue

Comment: @STEVER do you have any updates on this issue? How long did it take to get your site indexed?

Comment: it depends, for our case it was about a week

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Google takes more time with SPA than with standard websites. I had the same reflection when I pushed my portfolio. 
The results were "human readable" around two weeks after the push, here's a screenshot of the present result:

[image: Angularjs website Google results]

Comment: it's already more than 2 weeks after we pushed the changes :(

Comment: Sorry guys if that wasn't technical enough but it's an answer out of experience on an already foggy subject...

Answer (score -1):

Using angular 3.17

For changing url enable HTML5 in your config file. 
$locationProvider
.html5Mode(true)

and on your index page add this in your header:

```
<base href="/">
```

HTML 5 is needed to update your url. # is old according to Google and Google recommends not using pre-render unless it serves a greater purpose than just seo.

This is the directive I used:

```
app.directive('someDirective',['$location', function(location){
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    controller: 'someController',
    link: function(scope,element,attrs){
        scope.$on('event-change', function(event, data){
            //some function prepares new url
            var newUrl = someController.someFunction();

            location.url(url);
        })
    }
}
```

$location is passed in the directive to allow the use of location in the link function.

scope.$on is used to trigger the directive. This is helpful because often your directives will load before your data is ready (could be the issue you're facing please post more code).

someController is passing a factory as a dependent. The factory broadcasts the scope.$on event. I often set the data in the factory at the beginning of page load, once promises have been resolved. This allows me to avoid using $watch or $observe.

I've had no problems creating dynamic meta description. Url was a pain to figure out. Here is a directive example:

```
app.directive('someDirective', function(){
return {
 scope: {
   metaDescription: '@'
 },
 controller: 'someController',
 replace: true,
  template: '<meta name="description" content="{{metaDescription}}">',
 link: function(scope,element, attrs){
 scope.$on('some-event', function(event, data){
 //some controller function that prepares and returns dynamic meta description
 var newMeta = someController.someFunction();
 //assigns value in your template
 scope.metaDescription = newMeta;

  })
```

}
});

My understanding is using @ isolates the scope to inside the directive...meaning you have to pass the value from the DOM or create the value inside the directive.

And finally in your index.html file add the directive inside the header:

```
<header>
   <some-directive></some-directive>
</header>
```

Your output should be your template with the meta description inside. If this doesn't work then you could try adding a watch or observe in the link function. Or you could broadcast right from the parent controller and use that broadcast event to activate your scope.$on.

Comment: could you show me example of your application and how is it parsed by google. because it looks like you don't see the exact problem